# Json serializatjion, Howto add Object type name like 'Product'  in front of every rows inside Json?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, json

I want the following structure for my Json result:

> ```
> {"total":"14", "page":"1", "records":"133",
> ```
>
> "rows":[Product {"id":"1","Code":"ANIMAL","Description":"Description1"},
>   Product {"id":"2","Code":"FOOD","Description":"Description FOOD"},
>   Product {"id":"3","Code":"CLASS","Description":"Description CLASS"}]}

But what I got is following:

> ```
> {"total":"14", "page":"1", "records":"133",
> ```
>
> "rows":[{"id":"1","Code":"ANIMAL","Description":"Description1"},
>   {"id":"2","Code":"FOOD","Description":"Description FOOD"},
>   {"id":"3","Code":"CLASS","Description":"Description CLASS"}]}

And here is the code snippet I used to generate/Serialize the Json object:

```
public ActionResult ReturnJSON()
{
    List<Product> productRows;
    productRows = new List<Product>();
    foreach (Product p in apiDB.Products)
    {
        productRows.Add(p);
    }

    totalRecords = apiDB.Products.Count(); ;
    totalpage = 10;  // Simplified for demostration

    var jsonData = new {
        total = totalpage,
        page = page,
        records = totalRecords,
        rows = productRows
    };                

    return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

What's the best way to achieve that?

Comment: You shouldn't need to use the `JavaScriptSerializer`

Comment: Yeah, that's right, I don't, just add it for testing, will remove that

Comment: Hmm re-reading your code I believe my answer was wrong. How are you looking at the raw html? Using something like fiddler? I think firebug may just be appending those if the raw html doesn't have them...

Comment: @kmcc049 thanks for the the tip about fiddler, confirmed that the plain text send from server don't have those 'Object', Firebug add that for me. Also changed my question, it is different now, I just reuse the information for a different new question.

Comment: sweet as Fiddler has come in pretty handy for a number of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is invalid JSON (The `Product` node cannot be flying around like this):

```
[Product {"id":", ... }, Product {"id", ...}]
```

And you cannot add `:` after it because `rows` is an array.

There is no JSON serializer in .NET that produces invalid output. If you want to produce such result you will have to hardcode it manually yourself using strings.

Comment: Make sense, I will take it as answer.

Comment: I think you was right, and validator confirmed what you said. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

look at the `DataContractJsonSerializer`. Theres an example of it being used here.
http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/02/NET-35-JSON-Serialization-using-the-DataContractJsonSerializer.aspx

in action

```
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Result));
var data = new Result() { page = 10, total = 12 };
data.Products = new ProductList { new Product { Name = "asd" },  new Product { Name = "Asddsdsd" }  };
Response.Clear();
ser.WriteObject(Response.OutputStream,data);
```

definition of objects

```
    [CollectionDataContract(ItemName="Product")]
    public class ProductList : List<Product> {

    }

    public class Product{
        [DataMember]
        public string Description{ get; set; }
        ....
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Result {
        [DataMember]
        public int total { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int page { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public ProductList Products { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I probably need try it out by myself, but from the article it is not clear to me how could I achieve what I want.

Comment: thanks for the example, when trying the code you provided, I realized that same problem here, I need my Json object have Product Array as an child element inside. Not sure how could I achieve that. One obvious solution would be write my Json object at a even higher level with Total and page and have Array/Collection with Product as [DataMember] maybe?

Comment: Yes you will need to follow a similar structure to what I have so you can use the `[CollectionDataContract(ItemName="Product")]` attribute to set the name of each element in the product list.

Comment: {"Products":[{"Description":null},{"Description":null}],"page":10,"total":12}. That is the result I got, any idea?